# How to avoid horizontal scroll on website

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, mobile-website

I recently made a tribute page using html and CSS. The website looks fine on desktop but on mobile,a horizontal scroll bar appears and make the website look left aligned.I think its because the images exceed the parent container but I am unable to fix it.

Github pages: https://rahulviveknair.github.io/Coldplay-Tribute-Page/

Code hosted on github: https://github.com/RahulVivekNair/Coldplay-Tribute-Page

The code used to adjust image but does not seem to be working

```css
#image {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to do the following:

1. remove `margin` and `padding` from the `body`, and set its width to `100%`, in order not to rely on the default width applied by the browser:

```
body{padding:0; margin:0; width:100%;}
```

2. set a `max-width` if the disks cover:

```
#image-grid img {max-width: 100%;}
```

3. change the `font-size` of the title with media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    h1 { font-size: 30px; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbar only appears when your header "COLDPLAY" is getting too big/wide, which is due to its font-size. So you should use a media query for `#title` or `h1` where you define a smaller `font-size` setting.

Comment: I added media queries to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

Try also wen do debugging to unable cache in DevTools(if you use Chrome).
Usually files are not updating and you don't see any result even if you change something.
Also check this page if you are beginner [CSS Tricks](http://phpbuzz.co/friends/css-tricks)

P.S. I also started with CodeCamp good luck on next assignments

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove both `@media` for the `h1` and replace them with:

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: calc(5vmin + 16px); /* (320,32)(1280,80) */
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
}
```

This `calc()` calculates the `h1.font-size` using linear equation **y=mx+b** ([MathIsFun: linear equation](https://www.mathsisfun.com/equation_of_line.html)) with points

- point1 x1=320px y1=32px, fontsize 32px on a 320px display
- point2 x2=1280px y2=80px, fontsize 80px on a 1280px display

and all `h1.font-size` for all display sizes inbetween/beyond (I tested this with your Codepen).

2. Did the same trick with the 'album' images by adding `column-count` and `column-width`

```
    #image-grid {
      column-count: 3;
      column-width: calc(8.75vw + 252px); /* (320,280)(1920,420) */
      ...
    }
```

3. Finally change CSS `#image { max-width: 100% }` to `img { width: 100% }` and all the images on the page resize responsively
4. See my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/MWKRwXY?editors=0100)

**Note** anything smaller than 320x320 can be considered a 'smartwatch'!

Comment: Wow,definitely a cool way to achieve the desired effect.I wasn't aware that this could be done.I'll try to implement this in future projects!

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy, all you need to do is set the overflow-x value to hidden, if you only want to avoid a horizontal scrollbar and not a vertical one.
However, this will cut off things that go beyond the scrollbar, so you need to fix those widths as well.